# How can you choose one of multiple forms on a webpage to POST data to using HttpClient?

Tags: c#, php, html, asp.net, .net

I'm creating a method that will go to our university catalog website and return the degree plan for the selected school year. This is my code to send a POST request to the dropdown box to select the school year.

```
        // Post to catalog website to choose catalog year
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string catalogURL = "http://catalog.cpp.edu/index.php";

        //Example choose 2015/16 catalog (value = "8")
        //input parameter for drop down box in catalog
        var parameter = new Dictionary<string,string>{ { "value", "8" } };
        var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameter);
        var response = await client.PostAsync(catalogURL, encodedContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            //get content:
            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ().ConfigureAwait (false);
            //return html doc for catalog year
            return responseContent;
        }
```

However, I don't believe it's working. It's returning the html doc for the default page, the 2016/17 catalog, not the 2015/16 catalog. I think it may not be posting to the correct form, as there is another one before the drop down box: a search bar. What am I doing wrong?

This is what the source code looks like for the drop down box that I want to access:

```
    <form name="select_catalog" method="post" action="/index.php" style="margin: 0px">
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr valign="top">
            <td>
              <select tabindex="201" name="catalog" title="select a catalog" id="select_catalog">
                 <option value="10" selected> 2016-2017 University Catalog</option>
                 <option value="8"> 2015-2016 University Catalog</option>
                 <option value="9"> 2014-2015 University Catalog</option>
                 <option value="5"> 2013-2014 University Catalog</option>
                 <option value="4"> 2012-2013 University Catalog</option>
              </select>
            </td>
```

*Note: the url for the page remains the same regardless of the year selected, but the linke to the curriculum plans are different.

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I don't have much experience with C# or .NET

Comment: I suggest you use javascript/ajax in posting your desired data on a certain form of a page. you can do so by just target it using its name attribute with the help of jquery maybe. You can even target specific fields or input elements with that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you don't post to a form, a form posts to a URL. So you have most of the details right already. The issues you have are:

1. You named the input incorrectly. Instead of `value` it should be `catalog` to match the `name` attribute of the `select` input.
2. You are also missing a form field:

   ```
   <input type="submit" title="Select a Catalog" name="sel_cat_submit" value="GO" ...>
   ```

So you need to simply change your parameters to this:

```
var parameter = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "catalog", "8" },
    { "sel_cat_submit", "GO" }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect!